# rsnapshot - glitch adding per-backup-point parameter?

Tags: rsync

I am attempting to rsnapshot from different server environments, which requires different rsync arguments.  The fix for my problem appears to be to use per-backup-point parameters.

from the manual (rsnapshot)

> backup   /var/     localhost/   one_fs=1
>
> This is the same as the other examples, but notice the fourth column.  This is how you specify per-backup-point options to over-ride global settings.  This extra parameter can take several options, separated by commas.
>
> It is most useful when specifying per-backup rsync excludes thus:
>
> backup  root@somehost:/  somehost    +rsync_long_args=--exclude=/var/spool/??
>
> Note the + sign.  That tells rsnapshot to add to the list of arguments to pass to rsync instead of replacing the list.

This issue is that the paramater I want to add has a comma in it.  No amount of messing with quotes seems to have an effect.

here's what I want to add

`+rsync_long_args=--chmod D0770,F0660`

Here's the output (from one of my trials with single quotes)

```
/usr/local/bin/rsnapshot configtest 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: /usr/local/etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 202:
ERROR: backup backupadmin@prime::shared_folders/ prime/shared_folders \
         +rsync_long_args='--chmod D0770,F0660' - Syntax error on \
         line 202 in extra opts: +rsync_long_args='--chmod \
         D0770,F0660' 
ERROR: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any guidance appreciated.

It is actually a little more complicated, as I need to change both the short_args and the long_args, but I think the comma is the show-stopper.  I have tried replacing the entire parameter string, too, with the same result. I have also tried "escaping" the comma with a backslash, all with and without single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use comma in a parameter provided through the extra options: the code doesn't allow it.

The `rsnapshot` code itself:

```
sub parse_backup_opts {
    ....
    # split on commas first
    @pairs = split(/,/, $opts_str);
    ....
}
```

My recommendation in this instance would be to use different `rsnapshot.conf` files per source system. You can pull out the common parts so that each `*.conf` file consists of as few lines as possible:

```
include_conf            /usr/local/rsnapshot/DEFAULT.inc

lockfile                /var/run/rsnapshot-remoteserver.pid

rsync_short_args        -avzSi
rsync_long_args         --delete --delete-excluded --numeric-ids --fake-super ...

snapshot_root           /backup/rsnapshot/remoteserver
one_fs                  1

backup                  remoteuser@remoteserver:/         root/
backup                  remoteuser@remoteserver:/home/    home/

exclude_file            /usr/local/rsnapshot/EXCLUDE-linux.inc
```

Put the common configuration into `DEFAULT.inc`, and common exclusions into files such as `EXCLUDE-linux.inc`. You can then use this `rsnapshot` configuration file with the `-c` flag

```
rsnapshot -c /usr/local/rsnapshot/remoteserver.conf hourly
```